# Visual Studio 2010 Report Viewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I have been trying to use report viewer for a couple of days now and got no where. I have an ASP.Net WEB APLICATION, not a WEB SITE. Which every tutorial relates to.

I used the report viewer last week in another project and it worked perfectly.

What im trying to achive is to create a new report using business objects. NOT a SQL connection. Previously when i used the report viewer when adding new DataSet to the Report Data window all of my namespaces in my objects library (a seperate assembly) were listed and I was able to select my busines object and drag the fields to the report.

Now every time I go into the add dataset wizard there is nothing in the datasource list. If I add the report to the objects library and create an object datasource then they appear in here fine. Obviously i dont want reports in the objects library, they go in the website.

Does anyone know why the add new datasource option is disabled for Web applications? (Accessed from Data > Add new datasource)

Can anyone tell me how I can use the object datasource in the designer in the report?

my classes i want to report on have both a parameterless constructor, they return a list for the get methods. and they are all serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for this by creating a reporting class library.

if anyone is interested I added it to my blog for future reference.

http://wraithnath.blogspot.com/2011/02/visual-studio-2010-report-viewer-object.html